# Stripping whitespaces in a numpy array

Tags: python, string, numpy, whitespace

I've had a pretty decent look around and can't find an easy/one line way to strip whitespaces in a numpy array::

```
print(type(p))
print(p)

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[{' SPL', 'GPU', 'bcc'} {'ANZ ', 'ROI'} {'ANZ', 'bcc'}
 {'GPU', '  ANZ   ', 'bcc'} {'bcc ', ' SPL'}]
```

to::

```
[{'SPL', 'GPU', 'bcc'} {'ANZ', 'ROI'} {'ANZ', 'bcc'}
 {'GPU', 'ANZ', 'bcc'} {'bcc', 'SPL'}]
```

Trying

```
np.char.strip(p)
```

results in

```
TypeError: string operation on non-string array
```

Thus, is this a list in disguise?

Little help??!

Comment: This is really not the typical use-case of numpy and i see no advantages here in using it. What is that? An array of sets of strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array of sets, so iterate over them. create a new set with the stripped elements, and create a new array:

```
p = np.array([{item.strip() for item in s} for s in p])
```

This uses a set comprehension to create new sets with the stripped elements. The original array is iterated over within a list comprehension, which is then fed into `np.array()` to create a new array.

Answer (score -1):

This is likely due to how you are creating your numpy array.

The following code works fine:

```
import numpy as np

p = np.array([[" asdf ", " asdf " ], [" afhffh hfhf ", " a "]])
print(type(p))
print(p)

p = np.char.strip(p)
print(p)
```

And outputs:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[' asdf ' ' asdf ']
 [' afhffh hfhf ' ' a ']]
[['asdf' 'asdf']
 ['afhffh hfhf' 'a']]
```

Comment: I did not downvote. But just some comment: sometimes we need to accept the users decisions to store data in some specific format. Often the user is wrong and some alternative storage is better (which he did not know), but these cases are often resolved by comments / questions / discussions without adding an answer. Assuming we can just change his data completely (sets -> array is a huge difference) can be quite wrong in the general case.

Comment: I did not downvote, and am not going to do so. However, providing code doing something different, without decent motivation or a reason, is super frustrating.